# File not found. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Project1.main(Project1.java:24)

Tags: java

I am pretty new to Java and I cannot seem to figure out why I am getting this error message relating to this error message: File not found. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Project1.main(Project1.java:24). Any help would be appreciated. I have tried running through command prompt as well as an online java compiler and both tell me that there is not a file to be found.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project1 {

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       // create file object
       File file = new File("input.txt");

       // create a scanner object
       Scanner scan = null;
        try 
        {
           scan = new Scanner(file);
        } 
       catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
       {
           System.out.println("File not found.");
       }

       // take number of men or women from file - first line
       int num = scan.nextInt();
       
       // create string array of size number of men to save men preference
       String[] menPreferenceArray = new String[num];
      
      // create string array of size number of women to save women preference
       String[] womenPreferenceArray = new String[num];

       // point to next line
       
       scan.nextLine();
       // loop till 2*num lines
       for (int i = 0; i < 2 * num; i++) 
       {
           // take first 3 preference and save to men preference array
           if (i < num)
               menPreferenceArray[i] = scan.nextLine();
           else
               // take next 3 preference and save to women preference array
               womenPreferenceArray[i - num] = scan.nextLine();
       }

       // variable to count prefectMatch
       int perfectPairNum = 0;

       // read till file has next line
       while (scan.hasNext()) 
       {
           // take a marriage pair as string
           String marriage = scan.nextLine();
           // split by space
           String[] pair = marriage.split(" ");
           // reverse the pair
           String marriageReverse = pair[1] + " " + pair[0];

           // count variable to check if men and women has same preference
           int count = 0;
           // loop through the men and women preference array
           for (int j = 0; j < 2 * num; j++) 
           {
               if (j < num) 
               {
                   // take first preference string using substring and check if the marriage pair
                   // is equal to preference string
                   if (menPreferenceArray[j].substring(0, 3).equals(marriage))
                       // increment count by 1
                       count++;
               } else 
               {
                   // take first preference string using substring
                   if (womenPreferenceArray[j - num].substring(0, 3).equals(marriageReverse)) {
                       // increment count by 1
                       count++;
                   }
               }
           }
           // if count equal to 2 means, both men and women have same preference, so
           // marriage is stable
           if (count == 2) 
           {
               // increment variable to check all marriages are stable
               perfectPairNum++;
           } 
           else 
           {
               // if count not equal to 2 means, both men or women do not have same preference
               // . so marriage is unstable
               System.out.println("Unstable " + marriage);
           }
       }
       // close scanner object
       scan.close();

       // if all marriages are stable, then output stable
       if (perfectPairNum == num) 
       {
           System.out.println("Stable");
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: Robert’s answer is the right one.  If the file cannot be found, why would you want the program to continue?  What useful function can it possibly perform without a file to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't just print a message when you catch an exception and continue on.

Here you catch the `FileNotFoundException` cause "input.txt" does not exist (at least not in the current directory). You print a message but still try to use `scan`, which never got initialized, as its constructor threw. So `scan` is `null`, and that's why you get the `NullPointerException` when you use `scan`.

To fix this, exit the program when you catch the exception. Since you need that input file, there's no way to continue without it.

Either change the catch block:

```java
Scanner scan = null;
try 
{
    scan = new Scanner(file);
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    System.out.println("File not found.");
    return;  // Exit the program
}
```

Or don't catch the exception at all and declare that `main` can throw `FileNotFoundException`. In this case the program will error out for you.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    // ...
    scan = new Scanner(file);
    // ...
```

To avoid an error with files, specify the absolute path to the file, e.g, "/home/me/input.txt" or "C:\\Users\\me\\input.txt" instead of just "input.txt".

Answer (score 0):

If input.txt doesn't already exist, you can create it like so:

```
File file = new File("input.txt");
file.createNewFile();
```

Here is a link to the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()

Comment: True, but what do you read from that file? Either you crash on reading data that's not there, or you process garbage.